# A simple question about rotations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Suppose I have some vector $v$ which is left invariant by a rotation $R$ (ie. $v\in ker(R-I)$). The statement I want to prove is:

*If $w$ is a vector not parallel to $v$, then $(R-I)w=Rw-w$ is a vector such that $\langle v,Rw-w\rangle=0$*.

Is this something I should be able to show from properties of rotations? Intuitively, I get that the rotation would be such that the "components along $v$" of $Rw$ and $w$ are the same, but I can't prove it.

This came up as part of a proof involving a space with a few more constraints than a general inner product space, but I can't seem to prove it and was therefore wondering if it was a general fact in inner product spaces, or if I need that extra structure.

Edit:
I'm thinking I should use that $R$ is unitary:

$ \langle v,Rw-w\rangle=\langle v,Rw\rangle - \langle v,w\rangle=\langle Rv,Rw\rangle-\langle v,w\rangle= \langle v,w\rangle-\langle v,w\rangle=0$

but this seems to kick the can down the road.

Comment: In what way does using the fact that $R$ is unitary "kick the can down the road"? Is there something that you feel is missing from that solution?

Comment: @BenGrossmann in the sense that I am asserting (without proof) that R is unitary.

Comment: @1729_SR Ultimately, whether or not that can be stated "without proof" comes down to you definition of a "rotation". For example, one common definition is to say that a $3$ dimensional rotation is any $3 \times 3$ matrix $R$ satisfying $R^TR = I$ and $\det(R) = 1$; from this definition it clearly follows that $R$ is unitary. If you have a different definition in mind, perhaps you should ask a separate question of how one should reach the conclusion that $R$ is unitary from this other definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to reach the conclusion that the image of $R - I$ is orthogonal to its kernel, which is equivalent to your result of interest.

One approach is to use the spectral theorem for normal operators. Another is to note that (assuming your rotation is in $3$ dimensions) for some $\theta \in \Bbb R$, $R$ must be orthogonally similar to the matrix
$$
R_\theta = \pmatrix{\cos \theta & -\sin \theta & 0\\ \sin \theta & \cos \theta & 0\\0 & 0 & 1},
$$
which corresponds to the rotation about the $z$-axis by angle $\theta$. If you can show that $R_{\theta}$ has this property, then the general statement follows.